# nmap results to find open ports for SIP

Tags: nmap, router, sip

I suspect that a firewall, or other security, on either the router, or on `tleilax` or `doge` is causing a problem with SIP calls.  How do I establish that the connection is allowed and not being blocked?

I just want to make a SIP call from `192.168.1.3` to `192.168.1.4`; or not even a call.  Ring?  Beep?  Ping?  Some sort of "hello world" connection.

```
192.168.1.1      netgear router
192.168.1.2      asterisk (vicidial)
192.168.1.3      ubuntu client
192.168.1.4      mac OSX client (not shown)
```

Do I have a firewall problem which would impact a soft phone from establishing a connection?

```
thufir@doge:~$
thufir@doge:~$ nmap 192.168.1.1

Starting Nmap 6.46 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-02-18 06:10 PST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.1
Host is up (0.0086s latency).
Not shown: 994 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
23/tcp    open  telnet
53/tcp    open  domain
80/tcp    open  http
3333/tcp  open  dec-notes
5555/tcp  open  freeciv
49152/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.14 seconds
thufir@doge:~$
thufir@doge:~$ nmap 192.168.1.2

Starting Nmap 6.46 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-02-18 06:10 PST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.2
Host is up (0.00027s latency).
Not shown: 997 filtered ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
80/tcp  open  http
443/tcp open  https

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 4.95 seconds
thufir@doge:~$
thufir@doge:~$
thufir@doge:~$ ssh thufir@192.168.1.2
Password:
Last login: Mon Feb 16 00:43:01 2015 from 192.168.1.2
Thank you for installing ViciBox Server v.6.0!
This software is available for free download at
http://www.vicibox.com. If you paid for this
software you have been ripped off. Please report
any fraud or abuses of this software to
abuse@vicidial.com. Please report any bugs on
the forum at http://www.vicidial.org

To configure the LAN settings type:
yast lan

To change the server IP in the database type:
/usr/share/astguiclient/ADMIN_update_server_ip.pl

Official paid-for ViciDial support is available at
http://www.vicidial.com

Free community-based ViciDial Support is available
at http://www.vicidial.org/VICIDIALforum

- ViciBox Redux v.6.0.3-141118
Could not chdir to home directory /home/thufir: No such file or directory
thufir@tleilax:/>
thufir@tleilax:/> nmap 192.168.1.3

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-02-18 09:14 EST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.3
Host is up (0.00075s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
2000/tcp open  cisco-sccp

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.15 seconds
thufir@tleilax:/>
thufir@tleilax:/>
```

see also:

http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.voip.sflphone/1948

Comment: Check output of netstat on both endpoints. Do you expect 5060/tcp or 5060/udp? You have only scanned TCP.

Comment: I'm not sure this is an InfoSec question, but a network troubleshooting.

Comment: @schroeder ah, maybe so, pardon.

Comment: see also http://serverfault.com/questions/85721/how-can-i-check-whether-port-5060-is-open-in-centos/85730#85730

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed more a network troubleshooting question than InfoSec.
nmap is a great tool for scanning ports but since you do have access to each endpoints, I would use netcat to troubleshoot this.

According [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol), SIP listen on 5060 / 5061 (UDP or TCP). To verify what port is listening you can use one of those tools on the SIP server:

- **lsof -P -n -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN,ESTABLISHED**
- **netstat -ant**
- [tcpview](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) (tcpvcon)

Once you figure what is listening, You can use Netcat to verify if a firewall blocks the connection/port.

1. Stop SIP Server, so the port(s) are not listening and free to use
2. Run: **netcat -l [-u] 506[0-1]**
3. From the client: **netcat *SIP_Server_IP_FQDN*** [-u] 506[0-1]
4. Type some random text on the an endpoint, if it appears on the other endpoint then the traffic is not blocked.

*-u is for UDP, default is TCP*

Comment: what do you mean by "type some random text on the endpoint"?  Just in any console?? That can't be right, you must mean in some sort of telnet connection, or similar..?

Comment: Please cf below, note that netcat need to be installed, you can call it on most Unix/Linux/Mac with "nc", or "ncat" if you have installed nmap. many other tools exist to test connectivity (socat, iperf...)

Answer (score 1):

To reply to your comment with an image:
What you type on a client appears on the other client:
[image]